# Joining and grouping to equate on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried to minify this problem as much as possible. I've got two tables which share some Id's (among other columns)

```
 id       id
----     ----
  1        1
  1        1
  2        1
           2
           2
```

Firstly, I can get each table to resolve to a simple count of how many of each Id there is:

```
select id, count(*) from tbl1 group by id
select id, count(*) from tbl2 group by id

id | tbl1-count    id | tbl2-count
---------------    ---------------
 1       2          1         3
 2       1          2         2
```

but then I'm at a loss, I'm trying to get the following output which shows the count from tbl2 for each id, divided by the count from tbl1 for the same id:

```
id | count of id in tbl2 / count of id in tbl1
==========
 1 |  1.5
 2 |   2
```

So far I've got this:

```
select tbl1.Id, tbl2.Id, count(*)
from tbl1 
join tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
group by tbl1.Id, tbl2.Id
```

which just gives me... well... something nowhere near what I need, to be honest! I was trying count(tbl1.Id), count(tbl2.Id) but get the same multiplied amount (because I'm joining I guess?) - I can't get the individual representations into individual columns where I can do the division.

Comment: What is "out-id"?  Your description of the calculation doesn't match the data.

Comment: CAn you explain your results? I would have though that the second row would have a value of `2` not `1`.

Comment: I've edited the table headers on my output, I was trying to be concise but now it shows - Id and count of Id from table 2 divided by count of Id from table 1 (which was written in q but not exemplified in table header)

Comment: But `2/1 = 2` not `1` @jamheadart .

Comment: lol oh yeah, sorry! edited - seems I've forgotten the simplest of maths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives consideration to your naming of tables -- the query from tbl2 needs to be first so the results will include all records from tbl2.  The LEFT JOIN will include all results from the first query, but only join those results that exist in tbl1.  (Alternatively, you could use a FULL OUTER JOIN or UNION both results together in the first query.)  I also added an IIF to give you an option if there are no records in tbl1 (dividing by null would produce null anyway, but you can do what you want).

Counts are cast as decimal so that the ratio will be returned as a decimal.  You can adjust precision as required.

```
SELECT tb2.id, tb2.table2Count, tb1.table1Count,
    IIF(ISNULL(tb1.table1Count, 0) != 0, tb2.table2Count / tb1.table1Count, null) AS ratio
FROM (
    SELECT id, CAST(COUNT(1) AS DECIMAL(18, 5)) AS table2Count
    FROM tbl2
    GROUP BY id
    ) AS tb2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, CAST(COUNT(1) AS DECIMAL(18, 5)) AS table1Count
    FROM tbl1
    GROUP BY id
    ) AS tb1 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
```

(A subqquery with a LEFT JOIN will allow the query optimizer to determine how to generate the results and will generally outperform a CROSS APPLY, as that executes a calculation for every record.)

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate in subqueries and then `join`:

```
select t1.id, t2.cnt * 1.0 / t1.cnt
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from tbl1
      group by id
     ) t1 join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from tbl2
      group by id
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: how can it be 1? 2/1 for id 2

Comment: This also "suffers" from integer math.

Comment: Why I've asked the OP, @Standin.Wolf . It's what they're expected results says...

Comment: @Standin.Wolf . . . The answer has been fixed to account for integer division.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* your expected results are wrong, then this is how I would do it:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID int);
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID int);
GO

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1),(1),(2);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1),(1),(1),(2),(2);
GO

SELECT T1.ID AS OutID,
       (T2.T2Count * 1.) / COUNT(T1.ID) AS OutCount --Might want a CONVERT to a smaller scale and precision decimal here
FROM T1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT T2.ID, COUNT(T2.ID) AS T2Count
                  FROM T2
                  WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
                  GROUP BY T2.ID) T2
GROUP BY T1.ID,
         T2.T2Count;

GO
DROP TABLE T1;
DROP TABLE T2;
```